# Noninverting input voltage seen on V+ pin of OpAmp

Tags: single-supply-op-amp, input-bias-current

I've built this exact circuit here, except for one variation: SHDN is connected via a 10K resistor to ground. The opamp should be off!!!

What happens is when I connect a battery (or power supply) to VBAT, somehow that voltage is makes it way to the V+ pin, which is connected to 5V (turned off ATM, I'm only focusing on Vin rn). If I connect a 100k resistor between 5V and GND, the circuit draws about 200uA when 3V is on VBAT. SHDN is at GND, the output is also at GND.

What on earth is happening here? This opamp is supposed to have an input bias current in the pA range. How is the input "getting through" the chip?

This is very important because this is a battery powered device, and I need uA of consumption when the circuit is off, not in the 100s.

The only ideas I've found from google so far are more decoupling (I tried adding 2x 10uFs, same problem) or that the input impedance was too high...

[image]

Comment: Is the op-amp unpowered when this happens, i.e. the 5 V supply is off?  If so, there may be ESD protection diodes that conduct on the + input that feed current to the 5 V rail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What happens is when I connect a battery (or power supply) to VBAT, somehow that voltage is makes its way to the V+ pin

It sounds like you are expecting no voltage on V+ (because the 5v rail is off in shutdown mode), but there is. This is likely because you are operating the op amp outside of the absolute maximum ratings. From the datasheet, the voltage on an input pin should never exceed 0.2v + V+. In this case you are exceeding it by 3v.

To fix this, you could disconnect the inputs to the op amp when in shutdown, or, if possible for your application, power it directly from the battery.

Comment: Dude of course! I swear I was within the ratings, but I did NOT think about that when I turn the 5V input off.

Comment: @AJ_Smoothie  Wait, so elsewhere in your schematic your 5V rail is getting switched off by the same SHDN signal that feeds the opamp shutdown pin?

Comment: @SteKulov yup it's all getting shutdown by the opamp to conserve battery power

Comment: @AJ_Smoothie Ah, ok. Then it all makes sense. Thanks.